# Do a callback from subclassed thread in main thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt4

I have a class that inherits from threading.Thread. 
After processing an item from a queue I want it to call a function that I handed over to the thread when starting it. Doing that callback from the run-Method will have it run in my worker thread. Is there a way to run that callback inside the MainThread?

Thanks & Greetings,
Sean

Answer (score 3):

You didnt mention intially that you are using pyqt. Qt has signals and slots built in just for this purpose. If you are launching your thread using QThread then it has the 'finished' signal that your main thread can be connected to on a slot. If you need even more control of the resulting signal you can emit a custom one from the thread with any value you want. When you construct the thread just connect its signal to the slot that you want to act as the callback. 
Otherwise you would be blocking your main event loop if you are specifically waiting on the thread.

Here is a link specifically about the new style signal/slots: http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html

It makes it extremely easy now to create a python signal with whatever signature you want and connect it in an object oriented fashion to a slot.

Also as a side note about PyQt... Some of the other answers here have suggested creating a loop on your main thread that waits to collect responses in a queue from its dispatched threads. That is essentially what PyQt does. When you start your app the main thread goes into an event loop. This event loop is processing events that stack up in its event queue. There are different types of signal/slot connections. If your two endpoints are in the same thread, then a direct connection will be made and the emitting signal will call the slot. If they are in different threads, then I believe it goes through the event loop so that it can be processed outside of the emitters thread.

Answer (score 0):

Push the method onto a queue and have the main thread sit and wait on that queue, running each method as it pulls them off.

Answer (score 0):

You can use condition variables and have your main thread wait on a message from the sub-thread. The sub-thread can signal the main thread to call that method.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.

The problem is, that I would have to hold the execution of my MainThread (that holds a Qt4 GUI) until the worker thread is finished and that would make the GUI unresponsive (The worker thread is doing database-related work which takes some time)

Comment: See my answer for pyqt specific solution. I think you alao might need to read up a bit more about using pyqt